# How to dynamically load the Bootstrap-combobox based on entered value

Tags: dynamic, twitter-bootstrap-3, combobox, lazy-loading, loading

I am using the bootstrap-combobox 
https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox
Right now I am getting the data which is a list of employees that is very large. I bring it back as a select list in an ajax call then populating the combobox. It is really slowing down the UI and unusable on mobile devices so I want to dynamically populate the combobox and not have to populate it with the entire dataset upon loading the screen.

```
function populateCombobox() {
    var i = 0;
    $.each(selectValues, function () {
        $('.combobox')
            .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", selectValues[i].Value)
            .text(selectValues[i].Text));
        i = i + 1;
    });
}
```

I cant seem to find the event to attach to in order to know when the user has typed in at least three characters  in order to filter out the data and reload load the combobox with those records that the user can choose from.

I have tried a couple different ways but cant seem to get an event to fire in order to perform the needed functionality. This is what I have tried.

```
$('select').on("change", function () {
    console.log('changed!!!!');

});


$("input[type='text'].combobox").on("change", function () {

    console.log('changed!!!!');
});



    $('.typeahead').click(function () {
        console.log('In Changed');

    });
```

Does anyone know what event to attach to in order to check the number of characters and reload the data?